# Return a value not found in the table with MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Assuming the following array:

```
$users = array(
    // User ID => Username
    '72' => 'jack192',
    '23' => 'robert1984',
    '253' => 'mary111',
    '4' => 'jason92'
);
```

and the following table:

```
Table myTable:
username | colFoo | colBar
```

I would like run a query like the following, however I would like the output to additionally include a column not in the table (The user's ID from the array):

```
$user_string = implode("','", array_values($users));
$query = "SELECT username, colFoo, colBar FROM myTable WHERE username IN ('$user_string')";
```

This would normally output something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [username] => jack192
            [colFoo] => 98
            [colBar] => 7
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [username] => robert1984
            [colFoo] => 
            [colBar] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [username] => mary111
            [colFoo] => 41
            [colBar] => 9
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [username] => jason92
            [colFoo] => 46
            [colBar] => 13
        )
)
```

However, I would like the output to look like this, with `user_id` corresponding to the key in the original array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [username] => jack192
            [colFoo] => 98
            [colBar] => 7
            [user_id] => 72
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [username] => robert1984
            [colFoo] => 
            [colBar] => 2
            [user_id] => 23
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [username] => mary111
            [colFoo] => 41
            [colBar] => 9
            [user_id] => 253
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [username] => jason92
            [colFoo] => 46
            [colBar] => 13
            [user_id] => 4
        )
)
```

I suppose I basically want to just feed the user's ID into the query and get it back out as output, without MySQL doing anything further with it. Is this possible to do purely in SQL without any additional PHP code?

---

*Note: I do not have write access to the DB I'm pulling this data from, and I did not create the schema, so I can't add a `user_id` field to it or anything.*

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to do it, almost a mashup of the other 2 answers. You can build a 'fake' table and `JOIN` it to `myTable`.

```
SELECT t.username, t.colFoo, t.colBar, s.user_id 
FROM myTable t 
LEFT JOIN
   (
    SELECT 72 as user_id, 'jack192' as username
       UNION SELECT 23 as user_id, 'robert1984' as username
       UNION SELECT 253 as user_id, 'mary111' as username
       UNION SELECT 4 as user_id, 'jason92' as username
   ) s
ON t.username = s.username;
```

SQLFiddle example - [sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64650/2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64650/2)

The `fake` table structure can be created by a php `foreach` loop.

```
$select = '';
foreach ($users as $k => $v){
$select .=  "UNION SELECT $k as user_id, '$v' as username\n";
}
echo ltrim($select, "UNION ");
```

Still a tedious, and not ideal solution, but another option.

Comment: Definitely the best answer so far. I'll look into this.

Answer (score 0):

You might try CASE

```
SELECT username, colFoo, colBar,
CASE `username`
  WHEN 'jack192' THEN SELECT 72;
  WHEN 'robert1984' THEN SELECT 23;
  ELSE SELECT NULL;
...
END CASE userid
FROM myTable ...
```

It will get a bit cumbersome if there are a lot of values in the array.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html

Comment: The case statement will be painfully inefficient, although it does have the advantage of being able to be generated by the php.  But it is not quite a SQL solution, which does not exist in this case.

Comment: @Jon Downvote was not from me, just FYI. Thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with SQL alone because the id is not defined in the table (not withstanding the cumbersome case statement proposed by Hulka).

Less directly answer the question but providing an alternate solution:

However, you can make a 'small' modification to your php which will accomplish the desired result:

```
$user_string = implode("','", array_values($users));
foreach ($users as $k => $v){ 
  $query[$k] = "SELECT \"$v\"
                       ,username 
                       ,colFoo
                       ,colBar 
                FROM myTable WHERE username IN ('$user_string')";
}
```

the query is is basically the same as 'SELECT "6" as user_id, field from TABLE;' for each user, this which would return

```
6   field
----------
6   value1
6   value2
...
```

depending on your interface you may be able to prepare and execute, but you did not give enough details to produce specific code.

You would have to run the query multiple times, but you could push or array_merge.  Although, I personally think you should use the user_ids as the indexes for this new array.  That would require a modest rewrite of above.

Comment: Hm, thank you for the answer. I was hoping MySQL would offer a more straightforward way to do this. Multiple queries is not an option as I'm using a PHP-based MySQL proxy script (*long* story, don't ask), and each connection can take a few seconds.

I'm just going to use `array_search()` to find the user's ID based on the username (unfortunately this requires another `foreach` loop which is what I was hoping to avoid.

Comment: Then you have to go to Hulka's approach above.

Comment: @DC_ If you use array_flip, you'll be able to index your keys by username. http://ca2.php.net/array-flip